# Можно ли удалить первую ветку в гит-репозитории? Или хотя бы переименовать ее?

Tags: git

Можно ли удалить первую ветку в гит-репозитории? Или хотя бы переименовать ее?

Comment: У веток в гите нет порядка, и фраза "первая ветка" не имеет смысла

Comment: А если имеется в виду master-ветка, то удалять её никто не запрещает, как и любую другую ветку (но зачем?)

Comment: Любую ветку можно и удалить, и переименовать. Хотя единственную ветку, может быть, удалить нельзя (разве только вместе со всем репозиторием).

Answer (score 1):

ветка («branch») в программе *git* — это плавающий указатель на коммит (есть и другой тип указателя — фиксированный — это метка («tag»)).

у данного типа указателя имеется три основных характеристики:

1. имя
2. коммит, на который он в данный момент указывает
3. (опциональная) привязка к указателю в одном из удалённых хранилищ

имя можно в любой момент поменять с помощью команды `branch` программы *git*. пример:

команда `branch` без параметров покажет имеющиеся локальные указатели (звёздочкой отмечен текущий):

```
$ git branch
* first
  second
```

переименуем `first` в `bad`:

```
$ git branch -m first bad
```

и посмотрим результат:

```
$ git branch 
* bad
  second
```

ну а `second` переименуем в `good`:

```
$ git branch -m second good
```

и посмотрим результат:

```
$ git branch 
* bad
  good
```

две остальные характеристики (коммит и привязка) при этом не изменились.

являлся ли указатель текущим на момент переименования, никак не повлияло на процедуру (и результат) изменения его имени.

и точно так же никак не повлиял и порядок, в котором когда-то были созданы эти указатели.

---

удалить указатель можно с помощью той же команды `branch`:

```
$ git branch -d good 
Deleted branch good (was c0f165b).
```

главное: нельзя удалить **текущий** указатель. сначала надо сделать текущим какой-нибудь другой указатель (с помощью команды `checkout`). а порядок создания указателей, опять-таки, никак не повлияет на возможность их удаления.